# how to show a html page in a js file on google app engine 

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

```
$('#upload').click(function(){
        $('#main .right').html("{% extends 'a.html' %}")
    })
```

but this is error ,

how to make this code running .

thanks

Comment: it doesn't show error , but it is not right , cauz it alert nothing when i defined "alert('ss')" at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#upload').click(function(){
    $('#main .right').html("{% extends 'a.html' %}")
})
```

Do you mean `{% include %}`? I can't see what purpose putting an `extends` inside a script block would serve.

If you're actually templating into that `{% ... %}` block successfully, then you're including a load of HTML content. HTML content usually has lots of newlines and `"` characters in it, both of which will immediately terminate the JavaScript string literal inside the `html()` call and cause a big old syntax error. (Other characters that will cause trouble include `\` and `</`.)

If you wanted this to work, you'd need to take the output of the `a.html` template and encode it using JavaScript string literal rules. For a normal string this would be done using the [`escapejs`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs) filter in Django or the `json` library in general. However I don't think there's any way to do filtering on the output of an `{% include %}` command.

How about including the HTML in a hidden part of the document and showing/hiding it from script?

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess -- your element ends up containing "{% extends 'a.html' %}"? If so, it's because your js file is not being parsed by the template engine. In any case, you might be better served by making this an AJAX request, like the following:

```
$('#upload').click(function() {
    $.get("a.html", function(data) {
        $('#main .right').html(data);
    });
});
```

If you're feeling unusually fancy, you can add some animation to let the user know that a request is pending.